# Make a proper collision (prevent gliching through objects example)

Tags: java, collision

It took some time but finally I have a proper collision detection, what I now need to do is making the collision work properly and I'm kind of struggly to get it done right, so maybe someone has a hint or a good suggestion because I've been trying out for hours now..

In my code I will have a boolean that becomes true when a collision has been detected and when that happens I thought I would just reverse the move speed of my camera in order to make the collision work, but I was aware of the fact that this would cause some issues:

```
int Up_Down = 0;
int Left_Right = 0;

    if(Input.GetKey(w_Key)) { Up_Down = 1; System.out.println("w = " + Up_Down); }          
    if(Input.GetKey(s_Key)) { Up_Down = 2; System.out.println("s = " + Up_Down); }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(a_Key)) { Left_Right = 1; System.out.println("lastPressed = a"); }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(d_Key)) { Left_Right = 2; System.out.println("lastPressed = d"); }
```

Here I'm checking what key was pressed last in order to reverse the move speed in the opposite direction of the previous heading..

```
            if(collision == true) // true when collision detection is true
            {
            // See what key was pressed last and reverse direction by movAmt
                if(Up_Down == 1) {
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), -movAmt);
                }

                if(Up_Down == 2) {
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), movAmt);
                }

                if(Left_Right == 1) {
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetLeft(), -movAmt);
                }

                if(Left_Right == 2) {
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetRight(), -movAmt);
                }
            }
```

This is the only way I found to prevent any possibility to glitch through a wall, all other ideas ended up being glitchy if you try hard enough. Still, there's an issue with this:

When you have given enough different inputs the camera will slide off the walls instead of just bumping into them and stoping, so for example:

If I press 'w' and go straight into the wall everything works fine but if I for example press 'd' at one point and again go straight into the wall with 'w' I will slide off to the left since the integer 'Left_Right = 2' now, which causes the reversed movement of 'd' (to the left instead of to the right) even though I'm only walking straight into something..

- How do I get rid of this sliding effect?

So far I've not been able fix this issue without causing other problems, I'm thankful for any help.. if you need more code or information just tell me so. Thanks a lot!

UPDATE: Just setting the speed to zero wouldn't work, because then I will be stuck in the wall, the collision will always be true unless I back a way from the object:

```
            if(collision == true)
            {
                if(Input.GetKey(w_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), 0);
                if(Input.GetKey(s_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetBack(), 0);
                if(Input.GetKey(a_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetLeft(), 0);
                if(Input.GetKey(d_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetRight(), 0);
            }
```

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with java in particular, as you're asking for the general concept, which will be the same in every language.

How about the following Idea: you've got your current objects, its current velocity plus its current accelleration... don't move, unless the path you want to move through is collision free. So if you want to move through a want, don't cancel it with a -1, but stop moving completely.

Comment: If I stop moving completely (movAmt*0) I will end up stuck and can't move at all anymore.. any suggestions? Accellleration? The only thing I have is a speed value (so only velocity I guess)..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've tried out a few things and finally got it to work. Now when you move towarards a wall you will stop completely and when you release the key you move back from the wall a little - this gives it a nice looking 'leaning at the wall' feel:

```
            if(collision == true) {

                if(lastKey == 1) {
                    if(Input.GetKey(w_Key)) {
                        Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), movAmt);
                    }
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), -movAmt);
                }

                if(lastKey == 2) {
                    if(Input.GetKey(s_Key)) {
                        Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetBack(), movAmt);
                    }
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetBack(), -movAmt);   
                }

                if(lastKey == 3) {
                    if(Input.GetKey(a_Key)) {
                        Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetLeft(), movAmt);
                    }
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetLeft(), -movAmt);   
                }

                if(lastKey == 4) {
                    if(Input.GetKey(d_Key)) {
                        Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetRight(), movAmt);
                    }
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetRight(), -movAmt);  
                }

            } else

            if(collision == false) {

            if(Input.GetKeyDown(w_Key)) { lastKey = 1; System.out.println("w = "+lastKey); }
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(s_Key)) { lastKey = 2; System.out.println("s = "+lastKey); }    
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(a_Key)) { lastKey = 3; System.out.println("a = "+lastKey); }    
            if(Input.GetKeyDown(d_Key)) { lastKey = 4; System.out.println("d = "+lastKey); }    

            if(Input.GetKey(l_shift))
            {
                if(Input.GetKey(w_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), movAmt*4);
                if(Input.GetKey(s_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetBack(), movAmt*4);
                if(Input.GetKey(a_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetLeft(), movAmt*4);
                if(Input.GetKey(d_Key))
                    Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetRight(), movAmt*4);
            } else {
            if(Input.GetKey(w_Key))
                Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetForward(), movAmt);
            if(Input.GetKey(s_Key))
                Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetBack(), movAmt);
            if(Input.GetKey(a_Key))
                Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetLeft(), movAmt);
            if(Input.GetKey(d_Key))
                Move(GetTransform().GetRot().GetRight(), movAmt);
            }
```

Hopefully this might help someone else too!